# WPF with MVVM and Prismv2 - Event Bubbling?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

What is the best way to get an event from a child or grandchild module up to the parent Shell?

For instance, if I have a view in a module that is actually 2 levels away from the Shell, and I have a [Window behavior](http://pauloquicoli.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!B27CCFAA07B93BE8!10099.entry). Is the eventaggregator really the best way to do this? it seems like overkill. I just want my MainShell to watch for a change in the IsDialogOpen Property on the ViewModels in all my child modules. I feel like I am missing the trees for the forest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually achieved this with wpf 4 and visualStateManager.